# Why is the initial COUNT value changing after joining a table?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

The SQLite database is [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/)

The Question I have is, How many customers did each employee support, what is the average revenue for each sale, and what is their total sale?

For getting how many customers were supported by each employee, my code was this,

```
SELECT employees.EmployeeId, customers.SupportRepId, COUNT(customers.CustomerId) "Customers supported"
FROM customers
JOIN employees ON employees.EmployeeId = customers.SupportRepId
GROUP BY customers.SupportRepId;
```

And the result that I got was this:

```
+------------+--------------+----------------------+
| EmployeeID | SupportRepID | Customers Supported  |
+------------+--------------+----------------------+
|          3 |            3 |                   21 |
|          4 |            4 |                   20 |
|          5 |            5 |                   18 |
+------------+--------------+----------------------+
```

For getting the Total and average revenue, I updated my code like this:

```
SELECT employees.EmployeeId, customers.SupportRepId, COUNT(customers.CustomerId) 'Customers Supported', SUM(invoices.Total) 'Total Revenue', SUM(invoices.Total)/COUNT(customers.CustomerId) 'Average Revenue'
FROM customers
JOIN employees ON employees.EmployeeId = customers.SupportRepId
JOIN invoices ON invoices.CustomerId = customers.CustomerId
GROUP BY customers.SupportRepId;
```

And the result I got was this:

```
+------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
| EmployeeID | SupportRepID | Customers Supported |  Total Revenue   | Average Revenue  |
+------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|          3 |            3 |                 146 | 833.040000000001 | 5.70575342465754 |
|          4 |            4 |                 140 | 775.400000000001 | 5.53857142857144 |
|          5 |            5 |                 126 | 720.160000000001 | 5.71555555555556 |
+------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

After updating my code the Customers Supported column has changed, and I believe the previous data is the correct one. Thus my Average Revenue isn't correct with the new value. Why is the Customers Supported data is changing? How can I fix this?

Comment: The "Customers Supported" column isn't direct table data, but computed as a COUNT of `customers.CustomerId`. That count is different when you join your tables differently, therefore the values shown are different.

Comment: Then how can I fix this?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to get a close look at the table schemas you linked. But you could try `COUNT(distinct customer.CustomerId)` since the problem is likely that you're counting duplicate customer Id's.

Comment: The DISTINCT function worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `DISTINCT` function in the COUNT function and it worked.

```
SELECT employees.EmployeeId, customers.SupportRepId, COUNT(DISTINCT customers.CustomerId) 'Customers Supported', SUM(invoices.Total) 'Total Revenue', SUM(invoices.Total)/COUNT(DISTINCT customers.CustomerId) 'Average Revenue'
FROM customers
JOIN employees ON employees.EmployeeId = customers.SupportRepId
JOIN invoices ON invoices.CustomerId = customers.CustomerId
GROUP BY customers.SupportRepId;
```

Without the DISTINCT function it was counting duplicate customer Id's.